# GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

i have a problem i had try many solutions and it did not solve the problem

here is the logs

```
06-17 21:59:20.412 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
06-17 21:59:20.432 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter I/MainActivity: connectAPIClient().
06-17 21:59:20.862 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
06-17 21:59:20.862 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
06-17 21:59:22.352 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter I/MainActivity: GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
06-17 21:59:22.352 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-17 21:59:22.352 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 475: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
06-17 21:59:22.352 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00cb
06-17 21:59:22.352 11222-11222/com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter E/GoogleApiAvailability: Internal error occurred. Please see logs for detailed information
```

this is my code

```
package com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;


/*** REMEMBER TO ENABLE Google Drive API
 * https://console.developers.google.com
 * you can contact me to get a client_id.json or Client ID for testing @ jorgesys12@gmail.com
 */

public class GoogleDriveActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;
    private boolean isAPÏConnected;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_drive);

        //Initialize Google Drive API Client!
        connectAPIClient();

        findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Start camera to take a picture
                if(isAPÏConnected) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                            , "Error Google API is disable or permissions are required!"
                            , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            . setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

                    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    snackbar.show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Create a new file and save it to Drive.
    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "saveFileToDrive() Creating new content.");
        final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                // If the operation wasn't successful, return
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create new content!.");
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "New content has been created.");
                // Get an output stream for the contents.
                OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                // Write the bitmap data from it.
                ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                try {
                    outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                }
                // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("myPhoto.png").build();
                // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                        .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                        .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                        .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                            intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    //Disconnect only when the application is closed!
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
                // Called after a photo has been taken.
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                    mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    saveFileToDrive();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
                //Called after a file is saved to Drive.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { //succesfully saved!.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                    mBitmapToSave = null;
                    Snackbar snackbar =  Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Photo succesfully saved to Google Drive!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

                    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                    snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    snackbar.show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        isAPÏConnected = false;
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }
        // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and authorization dialog is displayed to the user.
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "* API client connected !!!.");
        isAPÏConnected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended.");
    }

    private void connectAPIClient(){
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "connectAPIClient().");
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```

and  this is my gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev76-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
```

and this is my manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/building_con"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".addMove"
            android:label="@string/add_move_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BuildingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SecurityActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_security"
            android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.alkhulaqi.ablularhman.counter.SettingsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PDFActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PersonalActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PrintActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />

        <activity android:name=".GoogleDriveActivity"/>


        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT 1:
i have enable the Drive API and create API Key (put type Android, set the package, set SHA1) i see this in documentations from the google developers console  . copy the ID for the key and put is manifest in meta-data tag .

the error is still here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794629/could-not-find-method-android-app-notificationbuilder-setlocalonly)

Comment: **NO**, THAT is so far.